# Can I define a static map as a function argument in the actual function call?

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, static, arguments

**UPDATE:** I just did some benchmarking of the core conversion logic for various solutions. Here are the CPU times in *nanoseconds* for a single iteration, averaged out of five million iterations on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/):

8 - switch statement

176 - static map

3800 - dynamic map

As you can see, creating a new map every time (dynamic mapping) is relatively time consuming. Creating the map once (static mapping) and just referring to it thereafter is almost **22 times faster**. But, coincidentally, the original switch-based solution is **22 times faster** than static mapping!

Hmm... I never considered dynamic mapping a viable solution but had hopes for static mapping. It's quite a bit slower than the good, old `switch` statement, but does 8 nanoseconds versus 176 nanoseconds really matter?

**End of update**

---

The **core problem** I'm trying to solve is translating from one "namespace" to another (in the general sense, not re the C++ `namespace` keyword). This is common in programming, usually solved in C++ with a `switch` statement like this:

```
#include <iostream>

enum MUSIC { ROCK, RAP, EDM, COUNTRY };
enum COLOR { RED, BLUE, ORANGE, WHITE };

COLOR convert(MUSIC music)
{
    COLOR color = WHITE;
    switch (music) {
    case RAP: color = RED; break;
    case EDM: color = BLUE; break;
    case ROCK: color = RED; break;
    }
    return color;
}

int main()
{
    COLOR c = convert(COUNTRY);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

The following is **my solution** (the templates will be tucked away in a header file somewhere). The `convert()` function works with any types that are valid for `std::map`, e.g., `enum` to `enum` and `long` to `std::string`. The first parameter is the key, or "from" value, the second is the default value if can't be converted, and the return value is the mapped, or "to," value. (Special thanks to @Yakk for help with template argument deduction.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "boost/assign.hpp"

template<class T> struct no_deduction { typedef T type; };
template<typename Key, typename T>
T convert(const Key &k, const T &d, const typename no_deduction<std::map<Key, T> >::type &m) {
    typename std::map<Key, T>::const_iterator it = m.find(k);
    return it == m.end() ? d : it->second;
}

using boost::assign::map_list_of;

enum MUSIC { ROCK, RAP, EDM, COUNTRY };
enum COLOR { RED, BLUE, ORANGE, WHITE };

int main()
{
    COLOR c = convert(COUNTRY, WHITE, map_list_of (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED));
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Anyway, notice that `map_list_of`, above, creates the same list every time it's called. I'd like it to be **static**. This is the obvious solution:

```
    static const std::map<MUSIC, COLOR> m = map_list_of (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED);
    COLOR c = convert(COUNTRY, WHITE, m);
```

But I'm trying to make it simple to use, in particular, as a single statement. Here's a **macro** solution, but I'd rather avoid that, too.

```
#define CONVERT(f,t,d,m) do{static const std::map<BOOST_TYPEOF(f), BOOST_TYPEOF(d)> m_ =\
    map_list_of m; t = convert(f, d, m_);}while(0)

    COLOR c;
    CONVERT(COUNTRY, c, WHITE, (RAP, RED) (EDM, BLUE) (ROCK, RED));
```

---

Does anybody know of some C++ **magic** (C++03, actually) that can call my `convert()` function

1. with a static map,
2. as a single statement, and
3. without using a macro?

Comment: You will have a new copy of the map for every occurrence of your CONVERT macro.

Comment: What's wrong with your first solution, or having a function to do the conversion that has the static map as a local variable?

Comment: @Neil-Kirk Yeah, I know that the CONVERT macro creates a separate map instance for each occurrence in the code, but I suspect a programmer would typically use it once, such as in a single, common conversion function such as `unsigned CipherToKeySize(CipherType cipher);`. (BTW, I doubt whether any compilers perform something like string pooling but for any type of object, but that would be cool.)

Comment: @Matt-McNabb There's nothing super bad about using the static map. It's really just a technical challenge to see if it can be collapsed down to a single statement for aesthetic reaons.

Comment: are you benchmarking with `-O3` ?

Comment: @Matt-McNabb No, I was using the `-O0` default. However, I just now benchmarked it with `-O3`. I had to declare the result variable, `c`, as `volatile` because the compiler was optimizing everything away. The `switch`-statement version took 1.4ns per iteration; static map, 4.7; dynamic map, 634. The speed up factor from dynamic- to static-map is 136.0; from static-map to `switch`-statement, 3.3. That further condemns the dynamic-map approach but makes the static-map approach a viable option vis-à-vis the `switch`-statement approach.

Comment: @Matt-McNabb Also, I bet as the key namespace grows sparser and larger, the static-map approach closes in on the `switch` approach. The Visual C++ compiler uses `if`-`then`-`else`s, jump tables, and binary search (sometimes in combination) to optimize their `switch` statements, so, ultimately, the map and `switch` approach could use conceptually similar logic.

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase names are conventionally reserved for macros, so I renamed them.

At some point you are going to have to do the work of coding how one enum type converts to another. The easiest way using a map is as follows:

```
Color convert(Music music)
{
    static const std::map<Music, Color> converter = { { Rap, Red }, { Edm, Blue }, { Rock, Red } };
    return converter.at(music);
}
```

This uses initializer lists which is a C++11 feature. If you can't use that, you can try:

```
Color convert(Music music)
{
    static const struct Once
    {
        Once()
        {
            converter[Rap] = Red;
            converter[Edm] = Blue;
            converter[Rock] = Red;
        }

        std::map<Music, Color> converter;
    } once;
    std::map<Music, Color>::const_iterator find_it = once.converter.find(music);
    assert(find_it != once.converter.end());
    return find_it->second;
}
```

This code might not use fancy macros but it's safe, reasonably efficient (one instance of the map) and readable (although I did do a trick with that struct there). There are faster ways but they are more complicated and probably not necessary for your use case.

If there are less than a dozen enum values, I would consider just using a switch statement however. It is usually faster than a map.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, the solution must be C++03. And I want the mechanism to be generalized so that only the data has to be provided by the programmer, not the logic, too. Also, your second solution violates my second requirement at the end of my query--one statement.

Comment: @plong You can call the function as a single statement. Isn't that enough? Requiring the whole thing to be a single statement is a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just simply use a static array and index it ?

```
enum MUSIC { ROCK = 0, RAP = 1, EDM = 2, COUNTRY = 3 };
enum COLOR { RED, BLUE, ORANGE, WHITE };
static const COLOR music_to_color[] = 
{
    RED,     //maps to 'ROCK = 0'
    BLUE,    //maps to 'RAP = 1'
    ORANGE,  //maps to 'EDM = 2'
    WHITE    //maps to 'COUNTRY = 3'
};

MUSIC music = RAP;
std::cout << music_to_color[music] << std::endl;
```

The body of your `convert` function can be only `return music_to_color[music]` (where `music` would be the argument) in this case.
The advantages of this approach are speed and lack of additional runtime overhead of creating a `std::map` of something simmilar. Disadvantage would be the fact that you cannot easily modify the map on runtime and it is more "C-like" than "C++ like" (you can ease the pain using `std::array` instead of static array if you need C++ interface: iterators, etc.)

Another way to do the same thing is to use template specializations, but it is a lot of typing and it would be difficult to maintain if you had a lot of values to map.

Comment: This is a good idea if the key enum begins at 0 and increments.

Comment: Indeed, assume the namespaces are sparse, so one cannot space-efficiently index into an array.

Comment: @user4438540 Please call them enum values and not namespaces.

Comment: @NeilKirk - yes, that's true. In most cases this condition is met. Even if this condition is not met, but there are not too many values - you can always fill the 'unmapped' positions in the array with some default values.

Comment: @Neil-Kirk Because my solution is not limited to enum values. For example, the template solution works with strings without changing anything, e.g., `string c = convert(COUNTRY, "colorless", map_list_of (RAP, "red") (EDM, "blue") (ROCK, "bananas"));`

Comment: @sirgeorge Those are just _toy_ programs to illustrate the logic involved. I wasn't actually looking for a solution to convert those specific four types of music.